# Cannot combine translucent Gradient filter with Shadow filter in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to mimic, in IE8, the effect of having both an RGBA background and a box-shadow applied to a div.  If I set an opaque background, I can use the Microsoft 'Shadow' filter to successfully achieve the box-shadow effect.  With the background set to 'transparent', I can get an RGBA background by applying the 'Gradient' filter.  But, if I try to combine both filters like so,

```
div#translucentBG {
  zoom       : 1;
  background : transparent;

  filter: 
    progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(StartColorStr=#80464646, EndColorStr=#80464646),
    progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#ffffff, Strength=5, Direction=0),
    progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#ffffff, Strength=5, Direction=90),
    progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#ffffff, Strength=5, Direction=180),
    progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#ffffff, Strength=5, Direction=270);
}
```

then the div will have the correct box shadow but an opaque #464646 background. Simply remove all the Shadow filters, and magically, the div turns translucent again.  This is pretty frustrating; since IE renders both effects perfectly separately, I can't imagine why it fails when combining them. I know there are probably workarounds and alternative methods available, but what really interests me is why the above technique fails the way it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explanation

I set up [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XWmey/12/) for people to see the effect (in IE8 of course).

I believe the reason why is that the gradient is registering as a "fill" value, and when it does, the drop shadow is itself filling in solid *behind* it. This is in effect taking away the transparency you are probably seeking (that is, it *is transparent*, it is just showing through to the drop shadow below, which *is opaque*, and thus covering up the background). Notice how the last `div` in my example fiddle is not "showing" at all because the drop shadow does not get applied when there is no fill to "shadow" for.

That the drop shadow is in fact filling in behind your gradient is further supported by the fact that when just a `border` is applied, as in the last `div` on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XWmey/13/), the drop shadow is going "into" the div as well. So the shadow is not just an "edge" property that does not fill in below the fill of the object.

### Box-Shadow Comparison

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XWmey/20/) shows the `box-shadow` implementation.

Note that [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-box-shadow) for `box-shadow` is different than the behavior seen with the IE `Shadow` filter. You were not "deluded by the behavior of the box-shadow property in FF/Chrome, which acted like an edge property," because *it is an **edge** property*. (Well, maybe you were deluded in thinking IE filters would work the same.) It does *not* fill in behind the box itself unless the `inset` keyword is part of the definition (in which case, it only fills to the inside). The `box-shadow` spec says (emphasis added):

> An outer box-shadow casts a shadow ***as if the border-box of the element
>   were opaque***. The shadow is ***drawn outside the border edge only***: it is
>   clipped inside the border-box of the element.

This is exactly what you are seeing in FF/Chrome. The IE filter was around long before `box-shadow` and the way it was implemented was obviously different. Note that I also emphasized in the above quote that the element is treated as if opaque, which means that even a `background: transparent` will show a shadow (as the example fiddle shows at the bottom). This is also different from the IE `Shadow` filter.

Comment: I appreciate the fiddle, although I don't have IE8 available at the moment. Your explanation makes sense.  I think I was deluded by the behavior of the box-shadow property in FF/Chrome, which acted like an edge property; if box-shadow were filling in the area behind the element, wouldn't that prevent the combination with rgba, just as in IE?

Comment: @sacheie--I updated the answer and added some further explanation for the comparison with `box-shadow` per your comment.

Comment: Thanks Scott, I wish I could upvote your answer more. The Shadow filter is often presented as a substitute for box-shadow, but now I see one has to read the specifications carefully before assuming anything.